# error in mandriva 2011 + ruby error no such file to load -- zlib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

The following is the error:

```
root@localhost # gem install rails -v=2.3.8
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Comment: Looks like your ruby interpreter was compiled without zlib support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `RVM`, Use it to install `zlib`

[RVM packages-zlib](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/)
The commands are:

```
rvm package install zlib
rvm remove 1.9.1
rvm install 1.9.1 -C --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

P.S.The rvm package command was renamed to rvm pkg in v1.6.25.